# Amazon Product Advertising Item Lookup IFrame Page Size

Tags: web-scraping, amazon-product-api

I am trying to scrape the iFrame returned by the Amazon Product Advertising API itemLookup iFrame. The itemLookup call returns this:

```
<ItemLookupResponse>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ASIN>0316067938</ASIN>
        <CustomerReviews>
            <IFrameURL>
            http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&asin=0316067938&exp=2011-08-01T17%3A54%3A07Z&linkCode=xm2&summary=0&tag=ws&truncate=256&v=2&sig=rhBGpRiaQ3L78yqgE5y30u8bF6zXsK3HL%2F2KpNMJns0%3D
            </IFrameURL>
        </CustomerReviews>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I can't seem to get more than three reviews in the iFrame. Does anyone know if there is a way to adjust the page size? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "page size" you mean the number of reviews you can get from the Amazon Reviews iFrame? 
If so, you can't set the number of reviews you are interested in in the request. The iFrame content, with the limitations you've already met, is all you can get from Amazon.

Also, be aware that your iFrame URL is valid for 24 hours. After that period, you'll have to generate the iFrame URL again.

Comment: sir,can you please help me in this ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659923/how-to-get-amazon-customer-review-on-magento-site